# Boot failure on any partition after upgrading to ubuntu 18.04 (broken UEFI)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 18.04, mac

I am in big trouble since I tried to upgrade my ubuntu partition on a computer with 2 disks and 2 other macos partitions.

After trying a first unsuccessful upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, I decided to do a clean install of 16.04  from a bootable usb key and then upgrade to 18.04. I however got a login loop issue when I have rebooted the first time.

At this point, the installation has removed the rEfind boot (that I am used to reinstall from macos) for the ubuntu grub.

I could press the option <kbd>**Alt**</kbd> key to boot on another partition. At this second reboot, I saw 2 new «efi boot» options. I tried one and saw an hexadecimal map.

I found it weird and rebooted. And I am now in big trouble because the default boot (supposed to be the grub sent me to a black screen after the «dong», and the option key just show me a unique **uefi boot** (I can't see neither the other partitions nor an external bootable key). I can't use the <kbd>**Cmd**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**R**</kbd> mac    recovery mode.

It seems that I tried the few things I can do...

Do you have any idea to deal with this situation?

Comment: I do not know Macs, but many seem to use or like rEFInd. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that I tried the few things I can do...

Actually there was another thing to do, and luckily it was enough to get out of this bad situation. I tried to [**reset the NVRAM/PRAM**](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) using <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**Cmd**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**P**</kbd>**+**<kbd>**R**</kbd> when booting. Then I could access again the other booting option with <kbd>**Alt**</kbd>, but I could not reinstall rEFInd because this manipulation has reactivated the **SIP** (a protection that I had apparently disabled).

I don't understand yet what was the problem, but I am glad it was enough to avoid the catastrophy. I hope it will help.